# Showing the app menu on the top mac window

Tags: c++, macos, qt, menubar

I have an application that on its main window, has a typical Menu bar, with File, Edit,, View, Tools, Help... with custom submenus. The menu bar is part of the form created using QtCreator, in design view.

I am trying to port this application to Mac OSX - I am a beginner in all things Mac, but I noticed that the typical apps have their menu on the main Mac window. And... it became a requirement, if I can, to move the app menu bar to the higher level menu...

I don't eve know how to begin, searching typical keywords did not yield anything useful.

I imagine that there is some type of object I can access and set, in case my os is MACX ?

Are there any examples, or documentation, on setting the top menu in Mac ?

using Qt 4.8...  c++... the Mac I have to build on has 10.6.8 on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/macosx-issues.html#menu-bar), Qt should translate your menu bar into a native OS X menu bar automatically, or with little work (though that doc is for 5.3). Have you tried doing this stuff already? If so, what problems are you running into specifically?

Comment: Thank you - I will try searching more... there are no actual problems but the menu bar shows on the app not on top menu - it is simply not translated. there is no error. oddly, there is a "Config" menu on the top mac menu - which was not created within the app

Comment: You are correct... the menu bars were translated automagically... It was a fix I made on Ubuntu because its menu was not showing up, that made mac decide to ignore native setting. As soon as I ifdef it for linux only, the menu showed up correctly